# How to deal with functions in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we have a function $m \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, we want to prove that $E$ is bounded from below

$$E(u)= - \int^{}_{\Omega}{m(x)f(x,u(x))}~dx.$$

I'm wondering if what I did below is right?

$$E(u)\geq - ||m||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \int^{}_{\Omega}{f(x,u(x))}~dx.$$

Comment: Is $E$ a function of $u$ or $x$?

Comment: $E$ depends on $u$ but you are also integrating over $u$ ?

Comment: @d.k.o. I made a mistake, the integral is over x, I changed it.. thanx.

Comment: Any assumptions on $f$? Is it positive?

Comment: yes, $f$ is a positive function @MaoWao. I'm concerned with the $m$ ... am I right by doing what I did to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In more detail: Since $m\leq \|m\|_{L^\infty}$ a.e. and $f\geq 0$, we have $m(x)f(x,u(x))\leq \|m\|_{L^\infty}f(x,u(x))$ for a.e. $x\in \Omega$ and thus
$$
\int_\Omega m(x) f(x,u(x))\,dx\leq \|m\|_{L^\infty}\int_\Omega f(x,u(x))\,dx
$$
by the positivity of the integral.